# How can I reshape usage data into minute-by-minute format?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I re-shape the following raw usage data into a “minute-by-minute dataframe”. Is there a special pandas feature for such an operation that can divide the raw data into the minute slots?

**Example of raw usage data:**

```
**Video-ID |        UsageStart** |  **Duration in sec** |

0 | 260581 |    2019-04-25 00:00:00 |   10 |

1 | 316288 |    2019-04-25 00:01:05 |   20 |

2 | 791714 |    2019-04-25 00:01:30 |   10 |

3 | 790503 |    2019-04-25 00:02:30 |   90 |

4 | 646034 |    2019-04-25 00:03:10 |   100 |
```

**Desired output: Minute-by-minute format:**

```
**Minute |  StartTime | UsageAmount in sec |**

1 | 2019-04-25 00:00:00 |   10 |

2 | 2019-04-25 00:01:00 |   30 |

3 | 2019-04-25 00:02:00 |   30 |

4 | 2019-04-25 00:03:00 |   110 |

5 | 2019-04-25 00:04:00 |   50 |
```

To be honest I have no clue how to do this. Perhaps this has to be done second-by-second first and than re-shaped to minute-by-minute format.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Not sure how you are obtaining the values. Can you explain why the `110`?

Comment: IIUC, you are looking for `df.resample('min', on='UsageStart').sum()`, but your output doesn't align with the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a pure `pandas` solution and I'm quite sure there are many of those tricky, oneliner methods to do this, but I'm still a basic pandas user.

I use a recursive function that consumes a given `duration` by adding its seconds to consecutive minutes, stored as keys of a dictionary `d`, starting from a `startime`:

```
def cumsec(startime, duration, d):
    if duration == 0:
        return d
    to_minute = (60 - startime.second)%60 if (60 - startime.second)%60 else 60
    to_add = to_minute if duration - to_minute >= 0 else duration
    d[startime.replace(second=0)] += to_add
    startime = (startime + dt.timedelta(minutes=1)).replace(second=0)
    return cumsec(startime, duration - to_add, d)
```

And then simply apply this function to every row:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# small df arrangements
df.columns = ["VideoId", "UsageStart", "Duration"]
df["UsageStart"] = pd.to_datetime(df["UsageStart"])


d = defaultdict(int)
for r in df.itertuples():
    cumsec(r.UsageStart, r.Duration, d)
```

---

In order to add possible empty minutes you can do the following, but I'm sure there is a specific method in `pandas` to do that (you can skip this part if this behavior is not wanted):

```
first = min(d.keys())
last = max(d.keys())

d = {
    first + dt.timedelta(minutes=i): d.get(first + dt.timedelta(minutes=i), 0) 
    for i in range(int((last - first).total_seconds()//60) + 1)
}
```

And finally create a new DataFrame:

```
cumdf = pd.DataFrame({"StartTime": list(d.keys()), "UsageAmount": list(d.values())})
cumdf = cumdf.sort_values("StartTime").reset_index(drop=True)
cumdf["Minute"] = range(1, len(d) + 1)
print(cumdf)
```

---

So, if your input was instead:

```
Video-ID |        UsageStart |  Duration
459224 |    2019-04-24 23:59:59 |   2
260581 |    2019-04-25 00:00:00 |   10
316288 |    2019-04-25 00:01:05 |   20
791714 |    2019-04-25 00:01:30 |   10
790503 |    2019-04-25 00:02:30 |   90
646034 |    2019-04-25 00:03:10 |   100
934784 |    2019-04-25 00:09:10 |   40
```

Output would be:

```
             StartTime  UsageAmount  Minute
0  2019-04-24 23:59:00            1       1
1  2019-04-25 00:00:00           11       2
2  2019-04-25 00:01:00           30       3
3  2019-04-25 00:02:00           30       4
4  2019-04-25 00:03:00          110       5
5  2019-04-25 00:04:00           50       6
6  2019-04-25 00:05:00            0       7
7  2019-04-25 00:06:00            0       8
8  2019-04-25 00:07:00            0       9
9  2019-04-25 00:08:00            0      10
10 2019-04-25 00:09:00           40      11
```

Comment: This solution seems to do exactly what I want, it seems to devide contiguous use that overlaps the minute boundaries into several minute pots. I will test it on real data. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I tested it with real data and I faced a minor problem. It seems that if I have usages that overlap the day boundary, the function will not work properly. Such usages may be, for example, a usage beginning at 00:00:00 with a duration of 86401 seconds, or a usage starting at 23:59:59 with a duration of 2 seconds. Is there a way to tweak the function to handle those possibilities as well, otherwise I'll have to cut those usages? Much appreciate your help.

Comment: There was a mistake when calculating seconds between  first and last minute (`(last - first).seconds`), and this caused problems with long usages, now I edited (the part when I consider empty minutes). I added just the results for 23:59:59 and durations of 2 seconds, but worked also for the 86401 duration. Let me know

Comment: I have tested it with 500 MB of usage data and it works fast and the results seems also plausible. Thank you very much!

Comment: Perfect! mark as answered if you think this solved your question

Answer (score 1):

```
# convert UsageStart to datetime column
df['UsageStart']= pd.to_datetime(df['UsageStart'])
# reindex and sum 
df = df.set_index('UsageStart').resample('1T').sum()
```

Comment: Thank you for this soluton, but here the usage duration of a contiguous use that overlaps the minute boundaries was not subdivided into several minute pots. Maybe there is an additional configuration for this pandas feature to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use `pandas.DataFrame.resample` method after setting you datetime column to index, 
something like

```
df["UsageStart"] = pd.to_datetime["UsageStart"]
df = df.set_index("UsageStart")

df = df.resample(freq="1Min").mean()
```

But I don't know if mean will give you the desired output